# java.lang.IllegalStateException: SinchClient not started

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

I am following the tutorial (https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-app-to-app-voip-tutorial/) to develop an Android app-to-app voice calling feature.

Please let me know suggestions to fix this.

Thanks
Siddharth

---

Scenario Details

1. For calling side I created an app via this tutorial : github.com/sinch/app-app-calling-android.
2. For receiving side, I used the sample app sinch-android-rtc-3.12.5/samples/sinch-rtc-sample-calling
3. I ensured that the Key/Secret & Environment were matching for both sides
4. Both calling & receiving apps build and startup normally

I am consistently getting this exception on Calling Side:

---

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.sinch.workshopskeleton, PID: 24797
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: SinchClient not started
                      at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.calling.DefaultCallClient.throwUnlessStarted(Unknown Source)
                      at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.calling.DefaultCallClient.call(Unknown Source)
                      at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.calling.DefaultCallClient.callUser(Unknown Source)
                      at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.calling.DefaultCallClient.callUser(Unknown Source)
                      at com.sinch.apptoappcall.CallActivity$1.onClick(CallActivity.java:67)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5612)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22285)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)

---

At the following UNDERLINED piece of code in the class
com.sinch.apptoappcall.CallActivity
=>

---

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (call == null) {
call = sinchClient.getCallClient().callUser(recipientId);  
call.addCallListener(new SinchCallListener());
button.setText("Hang Up");
} else {
call.hangup();
}
}
});
```

---

Comment: Hey, do you get a logcat that the client either failed to start or can you set a break point on client started?

Comment: Did you call `sinchClient.start();`? If you did not, then that's the problem. If you did, post the part of your code in which you called it.

Answer (score 1):

You should add this before you call sinchClient.start() to check if the sinch successfully started or failed

```
    sinchClient.addSinchClientListener(this)
```

```
    override fun onClientStarted(p0: SinchClient?) {
        Timber.d("Sinch Client Started")
    }

    override fun onClientStopped(p0: SinchClient?) {
        Timber.d("Sinch Client Stopped")
    }

    override fun onClientFailed(p0: SinchClient?, p1: SinchError?) {
        Timber.d("Sinch Client Failed")
        /// You should add logic to re-start sinch client here
    }

    override fun onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(
        p0: SinchClient?,
        p1: ClientRegistration?
    ) {
        Timber.d("Sinch Client Credential Required")
    }

    override fun onLogMessage(p0: Int, p1: String?, p2: String?) {
        Timber.d(p1, p2)
    }
```

You could read the reference [here](https://sinch.github.io/docs/voice/voice-for-android/reference/)